# E-mail notification on inventory list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating an inventory list for my company in Google Sheets. I want a script to notify me whenever a certain item is low on stock. I have written a script that does that, however, I encountered a problem because I am using a loop, to loop through the list. If more items drop below the given minimum I'll end up getting spammed with e-mails, because the script will count the same items again. Is there a way to set a limit to e-mails for particular cells - such as if an e-mail has already been sent for a particular cell, then don't send one again until it changes again, or something similar.

All answers are much appreciated. Below is my current code.

```
// Function trigger is on "change". If changes happen in the selected cells and it's time for re-stock this function will send an e-mail notification.

function checkValue()
{
// Get spreadsheet by ID
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
// Get sheet by name
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory_list_fieldwork");

// Loop from row 4 to 14 - increment by 1  
  for (var i=4; i<15;i++){
// Check cells in column C (3)
    var cellCheck = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
// Check item name from column A (1)
    var item_name = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
// If cellCheck is below 9 and cell for item is not blank, send e-mail notification
    if(cellCheck < 9 && item_name != ""){
      MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "There's a low stock on " + item_name, "There are only " + cellCheck + " "+ item_name + " in stock.");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can track what cells and what values have already been sent an email by using the [properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/). Properties are not erased after script execution. They remain there until you update them or delete them. But you can do all that programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create an extra column, wherein it will set an X if already notified by e-mail, and remove the X once restocked. This solved my problem.

```
// Function trigger is on "change". If changes happen in the selected cells and it's time for re-stock this function will send an e-mail notification.

function checkValue()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');  // Get spreadsheet by ID
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory_list_fieldwork");  // Get sheet by name

  for (var i=4; i<15;i++){  // Loop from row 4 to 14 - increment by 1
    var cellCheck = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();  // Check cells in column C (3)
    var item_name = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();  // Check item name from column A (1)
    var already_notified = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();

    if(cellCheck < 9 && item_name != "" && already_notified != "X"){  // If cellCheck is below 9 and cell for item is not blank, send e-mail notification
      already_notified = sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("X");
      MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "There's a low stock on " + item_name, "There are only " + cellCheck + " "+ item_name + " in stock.");
      }
      else if(cellCheck > 9 && already_notified === "X"){
        already_notified = sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("");
   }  
 }
}
```